# Find and Count employees based on date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I hope someone can help me resolve this issue.

I am working on a query which requires following as a result,

- Office,
- Subprogram,
- ServiceType,
- Total # Of Clients whose appointment date fall between given range of
  date and whose appointment status is "Done",
- Total # Of Clients whose start date is within 5 days from appointment
  date

I wrote the following code to get Office, SubProgram, ServiceType and Total # Of Clients whose appointment date falls within the given date range and whose appointment status is "Done"

```
SELECT
     fa.new_sitename AS Office
    ,fs.new_subprogramname AS Subprogram
    ,Fsrv.NAME AS Servicetype
    ,COUNT(fa.new_clientidname) AS Total#OfClients
FROM 
    Firstappointment fa
INNER JOIN 
    FirstServiceAppointment fs
ON 
    fa.new_appointment id = fs.new_appointment lookup
INNER JOIN 
    FirstService Fsrv
ON 
    fa.new_service = Fsrv.serviceid
WHERE
    fs.new_visittypename LIKE 'First'
    AND fs.statuscodename LIKE 'done'
    AND fa.createdon BETWEEN '05/18/2016' AND '05/30/2016'
GROUP BY
     fa.new_sitename
    ,fs.new_subprogramname
    ,Fsrv.NAME
```

and wrote the following code to get Office, SubProgram, ServiceType and Total # Of Clients whose start date is within 5 days of appointment date

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(fa.new_clientidname) AS "Total # of Clients receiving FV within 5 days"
    ,fa.new_sitename AS Office
    ,fs.new_subprogramname AS Subprogram
    ,Fsrv.NAME AS Servicetype
FROM 
    Firstappointment fa
INNER JOIN 
    FirstServiceAppointment fs
ON 
    fa.new_appointmentid = fs.new_appointmentlookup
INNER JOIN 
    FirstService Fsrv
ON 
    fa.new_service = Fsrv.serviceid
WHERE 
    fs.new_visittypename LIKE 'first'
    AND fs.statuscodename LIKE 'done'
    AND fa.createdon BETWEEN '05/18/2016' AND '05/30/2016'
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, cast(fa.createdon AS DATE), cast(fs.scheduledstart AS DATE)) <= 5
GROUP BY 
     fa.new_sitename
    ,fs.new_subprogramname
    ,Fsrv.NAME
```

Now, how to combine these two result sets into one and make it something like

```
Office, Subprogram, ServiceType, Total#OfClients (From First Query), Total # of Clients receiving FV within 5 days" (From Second Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Distinct
        fa.new_sitename AS Office,
        fs.new_subprogramname As Subprogram,
        Fsrv.name AS Servicetype,
    Count(fa.new_clientidname) As Total#OfClients,
    count(fa1.new_clientidname) as "Total # of Clients receiving FV within 5 days" 
FROM FirstServiceAppointment fs left outer join Firstappointment  fa
on   fs.new_appointmentlookup = fa.new_appointmentid
left outer join Firstappointment  fa1
on   fs.new_appointmentlookup = fa1.new_appointmentid
AND DATEDIFF(DAY,cast(fa.createdon AS Date),cast(fs.scheduledstart AS Date)) >=5   
join FirstService Fsrv
on fa.new_service=Fsrv.serviceid or fa1.new_service=Fsrv.serviceid
Where 
fs.new_visittypename like 'first'
                    AND fs.statuscodename like 'done'
                    AND fa.createdon BETWEEN '05/18/2016' AND '05/30/2016' 
            AND fa1.createdon BETWEEN '05/18/2016' AND '05/30/2016' 
group by fa.new_sitename, fs.new_subprogramname,Fsrv.name
```